# Intersection of compact sets in different spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a compact set in $L^1$ and $B$ a compact set in $L^2$. Determine if $A \cap B$ is compact in $L^1$ or $L^2$ or both.

My idea:

Since $L^2 \subset L^1$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is stronger than $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$,
\begin{equation}
B \text{ is compact in } (L^2,\Vert \cdot \Vert_2) \Rightarrow B \text{ is also compact in } (L^1,\Vert \cdot \Vert_1)
\end{equation}
therefore, $A \cap B$ is compact in $L^1$. However, I have no idea about how to determine if $A \cap B$ is compact in $L^2$ or not. Any hints or help? Thanks!

Comment: show that $A$ is closed in $L^2$.

Comment: @daw sorry, I don't understand. Why is it enough to show that $A$ is closed in $L^2$?

Comment: I think it is enough to show that $A \cap B$ in $L^2$ is closed because a closed subset of compact set is also compact. But I don't know how to show that $A \cap B$ is closed in $L^2$.

Comment: Are you working on a set of finite measure? Otherwise it is not true in general that $L^2 \subset L^1$.

Comment: @PhoemueX yes, here $L^p$ is defined on (0,1).